# What is the easiest way to know how many bytes of data is stored at a certain moment in a Python Queue?

Tags: python, serialization, queue, pickle

I'm using the Python Queue implementation (http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) and I was wondering how to get the actual size in bytes of the queue?

I know one can retrieve the number of elements in it, but that doesn't help me as the elements could be of variable size.

Also sys.getsizeof() doesn't help me.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Queue,sys

q1 = Queue.Queue(0)
q2 = Queue.Queue(0)


for number in range (0,1000):
    q1.put(number)

for number in range (0,10000):
    q2.put(number)


print "%s elements, %s bytes"%(q1.qsize(),sys.getsizeof(q1))
print "%s elements, %s bytes"%(q2.qsize(),sys.getsizeof(q2))
```

1000 elements, 72 bytes
10000 elements, 72 bytes

What is the easiest way to know how many bytes of data is stored at a certain moment in a queue?

cheers,

Jay

Comment: What do you need this information for? Is it okay if you just know the size of the elements of the Queue?

Comment: "the size of the queue in bytes" doesn't make much sense: it's a container with references to objects.  Are you talking about how many bytes it would be if serialized in some way?

Comment: @Rafe: The application I have has multiple queues which hold information to be submitted to different destinations.  It's possible that one of the destinations temporarily can't receive data, so the information keeps sitting in the queue. I would like to have something which blocks the queue from more data coming in when it holds for example 1Gb of data...

Comment: @ned: Yes, I understand it's a container with references to objects, ... In a way yes, what would be the size if the data in it was serialized in some way.

Comment: @jay_t, ok, but you seriously need to edit the question title, since _"the total size of the queue's entries if they were to be serialized"_ is not the same as _"the actual size in bytes of the queue"_

Comment: @jay_t: the size of a serialized representation will depend on how you serialize it.  You still don't have an answerable question yet.

Comment: @jay_t in that case you might have some luck with `sys.getsize(myqueue.queue)`

Comment: @Rafe: That doesn't work ... thanks for the suggestion though